# 'Being about' meaning in the given context

Tags: gerunds

Shashi Tharoor, an indian politician and a former International diplomat, in his interview to Hasan Minaj for a Netflix show said," we have had a party in power for the last four and half years which in many ways, has represented a radical departure from some aspects of what India has always been seen as **being about**".

I can't understand why he used 'about' after 'being'.

And another question which is related to the 'being' topic is

**I don't want being talked about**.

**I don't want being laughed at**.

How can someone be talked or laughed these are intransitive verbs we can't use 'being+past participle' here as they can't be in passive.

Answer (score 2):

Your last two sentences are ungrammatical; it should be "I don't want **to be** talked about/laughed at".

Yes, *talk* and *laugh* are intransitive, but the phrasal verbs *talk about* and *laugh at* are transitive.

Mr Tharoor's sentence is a bit convoluted, but he is using *be about* in [this](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/be-about-something) sense. He implies that India has always been seen as 'being about' certain political attitudes (regarding them as important), but the current government has very different attitudes.

Comment: Yeah perhaps the sentences were 'I hate being laughed at/ talked about'  And, Phrasal verbs are also transitive and intransitive? There's classification like that in phrasal verbs as well. So generally phrasal verbs are(verb+prep.) And preposition takes object if it's needed. So does it mean mostly phrasal verbs are transitive in nature?

Comment: [Here](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/intermediate-to-upper-intermediate/phrasal-verbs) is some information about phrasal verbs. Yes, I think most of them are transitive.

Comment: Actually, I think the only reason most phrasal verbs might be transitive is that most *verbs* are transitive in the first place. Phrasal verb usually involve a preposition, and if any given verb+preposition combination *wasn't* a phrasal verb, that preposition would normally be associated with an ***object*** being transitively referenced by the verb. As for example, transitive *He **picked up** a glass of beer* (he ***lifted*** it), as opposed to the intransitive phrasal verb *He **picked up** after a beer* (his demeanour ***improved***).